# Не нажимается кнопка

Tags: python, selenium, button

Для отправки формы в конце flow нужно нажать кнопку SAVE. Эта кнопка неактивна до того как все обязательные поля будут true
[кнопка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CojkZ.png)

я пробовал кликнуть по кнопке так:

`lass dragonfly(Page): saveLoan_btnL = (By.XPATH, ".//input[@value='SAVE']")`

```
def __init__(self, driver):
    self.saveLoan_btn = None
введите сюда код
def get_loan_data(self):

def get_loan_data(self):

    time.sleep(2)
    sample_text = "Auto name " + Helpers.get_random_str(6, letters=True, digits=False)
    self.name = UIInput(Helpers.find_element(self.driver, self.name_fieldL))
    self.name.set_text(sample_text)

    sample_text = "Auto iD " + Helpers.get_random_str(6, letters=True, digits=False)
    self.dragondly_id = UIInput(Helpers.find_element(self.driver, self.dragonfly_id_fieldL))
    self.dragondly_id.set_text(sample_text)

    sample_amount = random.randrange(1e5, 1.5e5, 5e3).__str__()
    self.gross_amount = UIInput(Helpers.find_element(self.driver, self.gross_loan_amount_fieldL))
    self.gross_amount.set_text(sample_amount)

    sample_amount = random.randrange(1.5e5, 2e5, 5e3).__str__()
    self.property_value = UIInput(Helpers.find_element(self.driver, self.property_value_fieldL))
    self.property_value.set_text(sample_amount)

    sample_amount = random.randrange(100, 500, 50).__str__()
    self.lent_so_far = UIInput(Helpers.find_element(self.driver, self.lent_so_far_fieldL))
    self.lent_so_far.set_text(sample_amount)

    time.sleep(5)
    self.saveLoan_btn = Helpers.find_element(self.driver, self.saveLoan_btnL)
    self.saveLoan_btn.click()
```

Таким образом, драйвер находит объект на странице, но не нажимает ее

Все поля заполняются правильно, никаких ошибок не возникает.
Пробовал дебажить до момента нажатия кнопки и нажать кнопку в ручную - форма отправляется.

В консоли получаю следующий текст:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input type="submit" class="btn btn-green-full right" value="SAVE"> is not clickable at point (1269, 904). Other element would receive the click: <div class="cookies">...</div>
E         (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.105)
```

[Дебагер](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgYZZ.png)

пробовал:

```
driver.wait.until(ExpectedCondition.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "myXpath"))).click()
```

```
wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.Xpath, "xPath")))
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath").click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том что кнопка не может быть нажата "self.saveLoan_btn.click()"
так как input имеет "type=subbmit"
Для отправки формы необходимо использовать
self.saveLoan_btn.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)